# Uniqueness quantification for inverse elements, for all elements of a group / uniqueness quantification for identity element, is this correct?

Tags: group-theory, predicate-logic, formal-languages, formal-grammar

Given a group consisting of the following :

- $\mathbb{G} = (\mathrm{G}, +)$ where :

  - $\mathrm{G}$ is the underlying set of the group algebraic structure
  - $+$ is an internal binary operation which follows the identities of the group structure
- some identities which axiomatise the group :

  - closure : $\forall a,b \in \mathrm{A} \big( (a+b)\in \mathrm{A} \big)$
  - associativity : $\forall a,b,c \in \mathrm{A}, \big( (a + b) + c = a + (b + c) \big)$
  - identity element : $\forall a \in \mathrm{A}, \exists e \in \mathrm{A} \big( a + e = e + a = a \big)$
  - inverse elements : $\forall a \in \mathrm{A}, \exists i \in \mathrm{A} \big( a + i = i + a = e \big)$

My questions are the about the formalization of the results of the proof of uniqueness of identity element vs inverse elements :

- if one makes the proof for identity element, one must prove (usually by contradiction) there is a unique element $e$ **in the entire set** $\mathrm{A}$ which follows the identification. From the result of this proof, I made this following formal statement : $$\exists! e \in \mathrm{A} \Big( \forall a \in \mathrm{A} \big(a + e = e + a = a\big) \Big) $$ *Is this grammatically correct? What are the other ways to formalize this?*
- if one makes the proof for inverse elements, one must prove there is a unique element $i$ for **each element** $a$ which follows the identification such that : $a\in \mathrm{A}, b\in \mathrm{A}| a \neq b, \exists! i_1 \in \mathrm{A}, \exists! i_2 \in \mathrm{A} | \  a + i_1 = i_1 + a = e, b + i_2 = i_2 + b = e | \ i_1 \neq i_2 $, when I tried to generalize this I wrote: $$\forall a \in \mathrm{A} \Big( \exists! i \in \mathrm{A} \big( a + i = i + a = e\big) \Big)$$ *Is this grammatically correct? What are the other ways to formalize this?*

When I compared $\exists! e \in \mathrm{A} \Big( \forall a \in \mathrm{A} \big(a + e = e + a = a\big) \Big) $ and $\forall a \in \mathrm{A} \Big( \exists! i \in \mathrm{A} \big( a + i = i + a = e\big) \Big)$ I denoted that I interchanged the following predicates : $\exists! x \in \mathrm{E}$ with $\forall y \in \mathrm{E}$ where $x$ can be $i$ or $e$ depending on the identities, hence because I wrote this statement instinctively (I have never taken an academic course on formal logic), I thought that the placement of the "small" predicate inside the "big predicate" change if the "small predicate" is acting on another or is acted on, *is this correct*?
*Do you know the word to differentiates the "big predicates" from the "smaller predicates", so predicates which take predicates as there entries?*